# SQL PLUS query result save to variable in batch file for further processing

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have been using the following command in my batch script to fetch the result from a remote database.

```
for /f  %%m in ('sqlplus -S debayan/[pwd]@[ip]:[port]/[DBInstance] @selectcommands.sql') do set theValue=%%m 
echo on 
echo "%theValue%"
PAUSE
echo off
```

on printing , the value comes as 
`echo ""` without the value of the variable `theValue` which should return the value of the select query.

My sql file has the following simple statement

```
set termout off
set echo off 
set pagesize 0
set linesize 500
set heading off
set verify off
set feedback off
set heading off
set serveroutput on
whenever sqlerror exit 16
whenever oserror exit 8
set autocommit on
SET ROWCOUNT 1
set heading off
select count(*)  from books;
commit;  
exit;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try `for /f "TOKENS=*" %%m in ('…') do ECHO set "theValue=%%m"` to see all  `…` command output processed in the `for` loop. (Use your command instead the `…` horizontal ellipsis.)

Comment: Hi this produces the same response asin the earlier case. However, i was able to generate the result to a variable by using `do @ set` and by removing all the statements before my sql query in the `.sql` file . That has given me the answeer i need. However, not sure as a programming practise whether it is a good thing or bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a temporary file, execute and finally delete it. Give this a try:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET MYTEMP=%TEMP%\mytemp.sql
echo set pages 0; > %MYTEMP%
echo select count(*) from dual; >> %MYTEMP%
echo exit; >> %MYTEMP%
for /f %%i in ('sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" @%MYTEMP%') do @set COUNT=%%i
echo %COUNT%
DEL %MYTEMP%
```